# dd cloning process keeps the partition table but not the logical volumes and their names, why?

Tags: rhel, dd, parted

So I Am trying to clone a drive using dd via the following command

```
#dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64k status=progress
```

the command does what it is supposed to for the most part but the usb which was sdb will not boot and times out at reached target system. So when looking at the drives after the dd operation the command did not for one save the gpt  as it should and I used parted to fix that. Even still if I

```
#lsblk 

<output> 
sda             8:0    1   30G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    1  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2          8:2    1    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3          8:3    1 28.8G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 25.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0    3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb             8:16   1 57.3G  0 disk
├─sdb1          8:17   1  200M  0 part
├─sdb2          8:18   1    1G  0 part
└─sdb3          8:19   1 28.8G  0 part
```

you can see that the logical volumes and their names are not present which is why  I think the system will not boot since it stop right when it is supposed to be switching over the the /rhel-root which doesn't exist on my clone. How can I use dd or dd + parted or fdisk etc to completely replicate the original system?

edit:: ok so  I verified that the volume groups where actually copied over but during conflicting volume names lsblk and vgscan and such will only show the one. as for the failed booting, the dd command copied over all the uuids exactly as well could this be a problem for the new drive since it has its own hardware uuid?

Comment: Are you trying to boot with both drives (the original one and the cloned one) connected to the same machine?

Comment: I removed the original when booting from the clone

Comment: That actually makes me wonder though if I cannot see the logical volumes because they might be the same name, I know vgscan will show an error if two groups are named the same maybe lsblk doesn't show duplicates? although it is still not booting so there is still that issue

Comment: That's why I asked :-) You can't have two active VGs with same name in the system. And by making a clone you have also duplicate UUIDs so it's even worse. `lsblk` shows only one `rhel` VG because only one is active, the one on the second drive can't be activated. But that doesn't explain the boot issue with only one of the drives.

Comment: ok so I just verified that the volume groups do exist on the clone by mounting it on another linux system. So now  I guess my question is why can't it find the root when booting from the clone?

Comment: One possibility is secureboot with wrong sig for the new device. Can you verify secureboot is disabled in bios/uefi ?